# i made check box dynamically but i can not see them

Tags: android

i have an app that make check box dynamically.
A button and edit text,i insert some thing in the edit text then click button after that a check box with that text appear.
but i have problem with that.

i am completely confuse, i cannot see them!!!! and i do not have any error!!!!????

can some one help me ? :(

```
...
    public int i2 = 0;

...
final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final Button bnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
//
final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
//
bnext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//getting text from edit text
    String str_et1 = et1.getText().toString();
    do {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb.setId(i2);//set id to each checkbox
        cb.setText(str_et1);//set text to each checkbox
        ll.addView(cb);
       } while (bnext.isDirty());//add when ever i clicked
    i2++;//this the counter
        }
        });
```

Comment: set a `LayoutParam` for the `CheckBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code -

```
final EditText et1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
final Button bnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
//
final LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
 LayoutParams params = 
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
 ll.setLayoutParams(params);

//
bnext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
//getting text from edit text
    String str_et1 = et1.getText().toString();
    do {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        cb .setLayoutParams(params); 
        cb.setId(i2);//set id to each checkbox
        cb.setText(str_et1);//set text to each checkbox
        ll.addView(cb);
       } while (bnext.isDirty());//add when ever i clicked
    i2++;//this the counter
        }
    });
```

Hope this code helps you!!
if its not working please let me know i will try to help more.

Comment: thanks alot my friend.
i change "getApplicationContext()" to "myclass_neme.this" and work fine :)

Comment: ok good, So can you please accept my answer with some voteup..?

Answer (score 0):

A check box alone is not a visible component. You will need to have a LayoutParam, then attach the checkbox to it to make it visible.